# Efficient way to return ID values from Access table for c# combo box

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

I'm using the following code to populate my combobox for further function. Is there a better way for populating my combo box in class context? I realize that if the number of records is in the thousands then probably this is not the best practice.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Book myBook = new Book;
    myBook.Connect();
    comboBox1.DataSource=myBook.IDs();
}

class Book
{
    OleDbCommand Comm;
    OleDbConnection Conn;
    OleDbDataReader Reader;
    string queryString;

    public void Connect()
    {
        Conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\Book.accdb");
    }

    public List<string> IDs()
    {
        string singleID = null;
        List<string> IDs = new List<string>();
        queryString = "Select bID from Books";
        Comm = new OleDbCommand(queryString, Conn);
        Reader = Comm.ExecuteReader();
        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            singleID = Reader[0].ToString();
            IDs.Add(singleID);
        }
        Conn.Close();
        Reader.Close();
        return IDs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you are using to populate the combo box appears to be technically correct. You are probably right that if it will result in a combo box with a **huge** number of items then it may not work that well in practice, but that is more a question of "UI design" (i.e., *"Is using a single combo box the right choice for having the user make a selection?"*) than "code design" (i.e., *"I'm using a combo box, so what is the best way to get the items into it?"*).

Comment: i got you bro.. thanx for the Answer..!!